# How to align two tikz pictures horizontally

Tags: tikz-pgf, align

If i use the code like \begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}, here is my result [image]

However, i want these tikzpicture are aligned horizontally. Can you help me solve this problem. Many thanks!
Here is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1][baseline={(0,0)}]
    \draw [rotate around={0.99:(0,0)},thick] (0,00) ellipse (3cm and 1.5cm);
    \draw [thick] (-2.34,0)-- (2.34,0);
    \draw [thick] (1,1.42)-- (-2.34,0);
    \draw [thick] (1,1.42)-- (2.34,0);
    \begin{scriptsize}
        \draw [fill=white] (-2.34,0) circle (1pt);
        \draw[color=black] (-2.34,0) node[below] {$F_1$};
        \draw [fill=white] (2.34,0) circle (1pt);
        \draw[color=black] (2.34,0) node[below] {$F_2$};
        \draw [fill=white] (1,1.42) circle (1pt);
        \draw[color=black] (1,1.42) node[above] {$M$};
    \end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=1][baseline={(0,0)}]
    \draw [rotate around={0.99:(0,0)},thick] (0,00) ellipse (3cm and 1.5cm);
    \draw [thick] (-2.34,0)-- (2.34,0);
    \draw [-stealth,thin] (-3.7,0) -- (4.4,0)node[below left] {$x$};
    \draw [-stealth,thin] (0,-2.1) -- (0,2.7)node[below left] {$y$};
    \draw [thick] (1,1.42)-- (-2.34,0);
    \draw [thick] (1,1.42)-- (2.34,0);
    \begin{scriptsize}
        \draw [fill=white] (-2.34,0) circle (1pt);
        \draw[color=black] (-2.34,0) node[below] {$F_1$};
        \draw [fill=white] (2.34,0) circle (1pt);
        \draw[color=black] (2.34,0) node[below] {$F_2$};
        \draw [fill=white] (1,1.42) circle (1pt);
        \draw[color=black] (1,1.42) node[above] {$M$};
        \draw [fill=white] (0,0) circle (1pt);
        \draw[color=black] (0,0) node[below left] {$O$};
    \end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: This `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=1][baseline={(0,0)}]` is wrong, you can have only one optional argument. Change it to `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=1,baseline={(0,0)}]`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! For second `tikzpicture` option `baseline` is not considered (due to fact that it is  not part of `tikzpicuture` options. Correct is: `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, baseline={(0,0)}]` or shortly `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)}]`

Comment: Amazing! I got it. Thank you for your support

Comment: @Pipnap `scriptsize` is not an environment. Inside TikZ, better would be `\begin{scope}[node font=\scriptsize] … \end{scope}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel done!

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem here is that `\begin{tikzpicture}` has just one optional argument; the value of that argument is passed to a `\tikzset{}` macro.

So your `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=1][baseline={(0,0)}]` is wrong; you should have this in your log file:

```
Missing character: There is no [ in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no b in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no = in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ] in font nullfont!
```

because the second bracketed argument is really read as a normal text (which can't appear outside a node in a `tikzpicture`.

The correct command is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=1,baseline={(0,0)}]
```

Which has the effect you are looking for.